Why does focus shift rapidly between SwiftUI TextFields when using external keyboard?
I'm noticing that shifting focus between two text fields with an external keyboard seems to create a never ending loop where the focus continuously switches between the two.
I can recreate this consistently in a simple playground with this view:
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
  @State var text1 = ""
  @State var text2 = ""
    
  var body: some View {
    VStack {
      TextField("title", text: $text1)
          
      TextField("title", text: $text2)
    }
    .padding() 
  } 
}

Connect an external keyboard to your device, make sure full keyboard access is turned off, then launch the app, and press tab on your keyboard.
Example on Imgur: https://imgur.com/a/5ydwhXg

Have you tried the simulator? I tried it in the simulators and it looks good, no looping.
